# How to Know if Keras is using GPU or CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Is there any way to check if the Keras framework is using the GPU or CPU for training the model?

I am training my model on GPU using keras but its so slow that I'm unsure if it's using CPU or GPU for training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets make sure tensorflow is detecting your GPU. Run the code below. If  number of GPUs=0 it is not detecting your GPU. For tensorflow to use the GPU you need to have the Cuda toolkit and Cudnn installed. If no GPU is detected and you are using Anaconda reinstall tensorflow with Conda. It automatically installs the toolkit and Cudnn. Pip does not install these when you use it to install tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print(tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
!python --version
```

Comment: I think the above code is only used for checking if GPU is detected or not and it is possible that my pc detects the GPU but trains on CPU.

Comment: My experience is if it detects it it uses it. If it is not detected then it will only use the CPU

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the GPU device:

```
physical_device = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(f'Device found : {physical_device}')
```

then you can check if your GPU device is on Used for training or not with this code:

```
tf.config.experimental.get_memory_growth(physical_device[0])
```

if this code returns `False` or nothing then you can run this code below to set GPU for training

```
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_device[0],True)
```

Comment: What does get_memory_growth and set_memory_growth have to do with the GPU being used?

Comment: set_memory_growth is used for changing the train device. 
for example:
`set_memory_growth(device1,True)` will change the training device to device1 and it will use the gpu memory.

get_memory_growth is used to check whether you have set memory growth to the device or not.

Comment: The documentation for set_memory_growth do not mention anything about changing the train device https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth so I do not think your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

here is the ref demo :

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_device = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(f'Device found : {physical_device}')
```